# How do I install QtGStreamer (Windows)?

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer

It turned out that I need to capture video from desktop with QT. The most frequently adviced tool for that was GStreamer. So, I installed it, installed all dependecies from README file, but I have absolutely no idea how do I compile this lib and link it to my project.

Any suggestions about how to use it?

Comment: I take it you read the [docs](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-windows.html)?

Comment: Yes, I saw them. And I can' even run a tutorial, I get an error: `gst/gst.h: No such file or directory`